# Strategry Infinite scrolling not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, ajax, jquery

When scrolled down, The next products are loaded. When debugged in it gets a JSON response. When switched to console I get the error Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:[image]
I will upload the Json response screenshot.
[image: Json response for Ajax Scroll]

Comment: Please describe briefly

Comment: Mr.Amit Bera. When I scroll down the page, I get a Json Response but the products are not displayed

Comment: You should add the part of code which you are using to achieve that in the question. Only then, it'll be possible for someone to help.

Comment: @AravindUmasankar, Have you solved this issue.

Comment: Yes. Need to append products to dom.

Answer (score 0):

Append response to DOM. It was missing. Its a plugin error.